# Trigger Segue from a table cell into another page

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, swift4

I'm trying to created a segue from my table cell to go into a next page.

I did

[image]

[image]

**SettingsTableViewController**

```
import UIKit

class SettingsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.title = "Settings"
        self.tabBarItem.title = "Settings"

    }

}
```

**GeneralTableViewController**

```
import UIKit

class GeneralTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.title = "General"
        self.tabBarItem.title = "General"

    }

}
```

---

**Result**

[image]

The segue transition seems to work, I see empty screen in there.

Any hints for me ?

Comment: what the problem ???

Comment: It show empty. It should show my general page as I created in my storyboard

Comment: add your GeneralTableViewController's code to understand the issue

Comment: I did it is on the post. Second block of code.

Comment: Does GeneralTableViewController's viewDidLoad hit on debug? Provide more code.

Comment: assign the class **GeneralTableViewController**  in IB

Comment: @Sh_Khan I did that already, see it here : https://i.imgur.com/BOh5D6p.png

Comment: @vivekDas : https://i.imgur.com/LFwNm1A.png

Comment: @shota : I don't get this. `Does GeneralTableViewController's viewDidLoad hit on debug?` you want me to place the print statement in there ?

Comment: Did you set second scene's class name to GeneralTableViewController on storyboard? In second picture it shows that it is just general UITableViewController.

Comment: you must implement the tableview data source methods like numberofrows, cellforrow

Comment: @vivekDas : really ? Are you sure that is the only way to do that ?

Comment: yes , what is the numberOfRowsInSection ?

Comment: I don’t have any table delegate and data source function at all. I thought I can achieve using storyboard.

Comment: i have never did without implementing the table delegate and data source. without table delegate and data source how tableview know about its data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show it as it's , then you have to make static cells , instead of dynamic prototypes , so select the table and from attributes inspector select `static cells` , but you still have to implement the delegate like `didSelectRowAt`

[image]

Comment: please include some sample code as part of your answer sir !

Comment: when you select it , automatically you will get 3 sections created by default , play with them delete & add , this needs a tableViewController also

Comment: Your suggestion works, but I don't really have to do this `implement the delegate like didSelectRowAt`